# Cmake. Select lib.so location folder

Tags: cmake

How can I create a lib folder and have lib.so in it?
Here is my cmakelists file inside lib folder

```
project(Library)
add_library(Library SHARED lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(Library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

In the main cmakelists file I write:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject Library)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

but it doesn't work. The file is created inside the folder where make is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) is a target property, not a variable you set. Instead of

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

you need to use

```
set_target_properties(Library
  PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
)
```

However, if you want *all* the libraries built by your project to be put into that folder you can alternatively use

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
```

somewhere at the top of your top-level CMakeLists.txt, as this variable sets the default value of the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target property for all targets defined after it has been set.